# JavaScript: Firing of events restores innerHtml property

Tags: javascript, ajax, innerhtml

I have a webpage with several buttons. Some of this buttons (let's name them BA1, BA2...) modifies the innerHtml property of an element of the page, which id is "ELEM_ID", after an HttpRequest, so it takes some time from the firing of the event to the modification of the innerHtml property of ELEM_ID.

When the Browser loads the page, ELEM_ID has a default value for its innerHtml, let's call this value "VALUE_1":

`<p id="ELEM_ID">VALUE_1</p>`

when I press the button BA1, after some time, this value changes to "VALUE_2"

`<p id="ELEM_ID">VALUE_2</p>`

The problem is that when I press the button BA2, just as I press it, the value of ELEM_ID.innerHtml comes back to VALUE_1 and when the HtmlResponse is ready then it's value is changed to VALUE_3.
Why does it happens?

this is some of the code:

```
var additional_order = [[false,'VAR_1'],[false,'VAR_2'],[false,'VAR_3'],[false,'4'],[false,'VAR_5'],[false,'VAR_6']];
var names = [];
var labelA = "cor_price_visible_";
var labelB = "cor_price_";
names.push("name1");
names.push("name2");
names.push("name3");
names.push("name4");

function updatePrice(n) {
    additional_order[n][0]=!additional_order[n][0];
    var request = "SSID=364c59b135c011c0734893225ab8a8a9";

    for (i = 0; i<additional_order.length;i++) {
        if (additional_order[i][0]) {
            request=request+"&";
            request=request+additional_order[i][1]+'=YES'; 
        }
    }
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            for (i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
                document.getElementById(labelA+names[i]).innerHTML=""+(result[i].toFixed(2));
                document.getElementById(labelA+names[i]).value=(result[i].toFixed(2));
            }
        }
    }

    xhttp.open("POST","services/livepriceservice.php/",true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    xhttp.send(request);

}


<button id="BA1" onclick="updatePrice(1)">Press Me!(1)</button>
<button id="BA2" onclick="updatePrice(2)">Press Me!(2)</button>
...
```

EDIT 1:
Debugging I noticed that the cause of the problem is the execution of something in the jquery.js script (there is a function that restores the default values of the nodes' properties), but nothing is called explicitly.

EDIT 2: That function is:

```
html: function(a) {
        return S(this, function(a) {
            var b = this[0] || {}
              , c = 0
              , d = this.length;
            if (void 0 === a && 1 === b.nodeType)
                return b.innerHTML;
            if ("string" == typeof a && !za.test(a) && !la[(ja.exec(a) || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase()]) {
                a = r.htmlPrefilter(a);
                try {
                    for (; c < d; c++)
                        b = this[c] || {},
                        1 === b.nodeType && (r.cleanData(ma(b, !1)),
                        b.innerHTML = a);
                    b = 0
                } catch (e) {}
            }
            b && this.empty().append(a)
        }, null, a, arguments.length)
    }
```

Comment: Hi, have you got live example somewhere?

Comment: Try to debug step by step what exactly happens on your `BA2` click

Comment: @DanilGholtsman Debugging I noticed that the cause of the problem is the execution of something in the jquery.js script (there is a function that restores the default values of the nodes' properties), but nothing is called explicitly.

Comment: And `onreadystatechange` is the only event in this scope you got?

Comment: @DanilGholtsman there is <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

            });
        </script>

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug dom change and get breakpoint on the subtree, or attribute change.

[image: Chrome Dev tools]

Comment: it's what I already did ^^... the element is modified by a function of jquery.js, I'm modifying the question to write down this function.